# How do I make a Secret Potion in The Gold Factory Game?

Tags: the-gold-factory

I know to look in the game files but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be:

> 1 gold bar, 1 iron bar and 1 health potion respectively

as seen in [base.js](https://gamehelp16.github.io/thegoldfactory/base.js):

> `else if(cldr[0]!=null && cldr[1]!=null && cldr[2]!=null && cldr[0].id=="goldbar" && cldr[0].quantity==1 && cldr[1].id=="ironbar" && cldr[1].quantity==1 && cldr[2].id==7 && cldr[2].quantity==1)`

The item with ID 7 being a

> health potion

As can be seen from the line:

> `items.push({"name":"health potion","price":50,"owned":0,"plural":"s","showstorage":true}); //7`